# What is the domain of the expression $\frac1{1/\cos x}$?

Tags: functions

What is the domain of $$\dfrac1{\frac1 {\cos x}}?$$

My book says it is $\mathbb R \setminus (2n+1)\pi/2$. 
Shouldn't it be $\mathbb R$ because this expression simplifies to $\cos x$ and the domain of $\cos x$ is $\mathbb R$?

Comment: You can use `$\mathbb R \setminus (2n+1)\pi/2$` to display '$\mathbb R \setminus (2n+1)\pi/2$' (however that's not a correct notation, but it's in MathJax at least).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression does simplify to $\cos x$, but only when it is defined.

Here's an experiment: Think of a number. Now take the reciprocal of your number. Now take the reciprocal again. What do you have?

If you started with any non-zero number $x$, then of course you finish with $x$ since $\frac1{1/x}=x$. But if you started with $x=0$, then you would have run into a problem since you couldn't follow the next instruction. That is why it is important to consider all the operations involved, even if the expression simplifies, when finding the domain.

Comment: +1 for emphasizing "only when it is defined". This idea is actually pivotal in learning how to calculate limits algebraically.